# How do you use native Python templating for a webpage (no frameworks)?

Tags: python, user-interface, view, html

In PHP PHP can be the templating langauge.  It seems to work well for that with no need for a templating system/language.

But, I can't find anything similar looking with Python for the language.  How do you do things like:

I took this from another unrelated SO question:

```
<?php foreach( $dates as $year => $year_content  ): ?>
<h2><?php echo $year ?></h2>

<?php foreach( $year_content['months'] as $months ): ?>
<h3><?php echo $months->month ?> - <?php echo $months->sales ?></h3>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I just couldn't find anything like this for "native" Python in the web view without someone's framework.  Thanks.

EDIT:  No offense.  Did not want a templating language.

EDIT:  Despite the downvotes, a case in point is Python 3.  [While there is a five year expectancy to have 2.x users going to 3.x](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63859/why-do-people-hesitate-using-python-3), not all templating languages support 3.x.  Jinja, for example, has "expiremental" 3.x support.  Why would I use that?  I wouldn't.  That makes me dependent upon them, where I'd like to be able to use things native, but alas, it appears I cannot.

Comment: You use a templating library. Jinja2 is nice.

Comment: Python is not PHP, so you can't expect everything that works in PHP to have an exact equivalent in Python. Why don't you want to use a templating package?

Comment: @DavidRobinson First is control.  I do not want to be a slave to someone's framework.

Comment: Why is there a negative vote?

Comment: @johnny: All programming requires working with specifications set by others. In PHP you're a "slave" to the specifications of the PHP language.

Comment: @DavidRobinson That has some truth.  We are a slave to lots of things, but I'd rather be tied to a larger group than a smaller one that might die sooner than later.  Example, I still use classic asp (I have to, not want to), and all these years later it still works.  I am afraid that with a smaller open source project, it won't, so that makes me a slave.  Sure, asp classic isn't supported, but it works with the MS modern products.

Comment: @DavidRobinson  Case in point.  Python 3 is out for four years.  Templating like Jinja is only experimental on 3.  That makes me a slave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has no *native templating* in the sense that PHP has. You *can* use Python as an ISAPI extension, which would give you syntax like `<% print "foo" %>`. Alternatively, you can write python scripts in pure CGI. Those roads are probably quite painful, and you'll be better served using frameworks – frameworks give you the advantage of other developers' experience as well as smoothing out the rough edges of dealing directly with CGI and HTTP.

Please see [my answer to a similar question asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7916343/418413).

Answer (score 1):

There's no proper solution in Python world for the problem, because mixing business logic and presentation is  definitely not a Python way. There was an old project called [PSP](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pyapi-psp.html) available with `mod_python` module, but it's certainly dead now for the reason I've described.

So frameworks or bare [WSGI](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) apps are two ways to go into web development with Python. There are a lot of templating libraries available over Internet:

- Jinja2
- Mako
- Chameleon
- ...

You can choose one that better fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Jinja2 http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/

It's a fairly simple templating language that allows you to create text file templates that can be internally programmed in a limited version of Python.

The example you posted might look something like this in Jinja2:

```
{% for date in dates: %}
    <h2>{{ date.year }}</h2>

    {% for month in date.year_content['months'] %}
        <h3>{{ month.month }} - {{ month.sales }}</h3>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```